# how to search data from array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have array in javascript. I want that when i enter any index of array in text field it should return the value of that array and display it i am using following code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <p id="demo">Click the button to extract the second and the third elements from the array.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
     var bb=document.getElementById('input_field').value;
     var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango","Apple"];
     var citrus = fruits.slice(bb,4);
     var x=document.getElementById("demo");
     x.innerHTML=citrus;
 }
 </script>

<input type="text" id="input_field">
</body>
</html>
```

but problem is that if i enter 2 in text field then it shows Lemon but when i enter three it shows only one Apple but it should show two because there are two Apple in the array so i want that if there are two then show two like wise.

Comment: Do you want only the value of that particular index or values from that index...?? I mean if you enter 2 , you want to return lemon alone or Lemon,Apple,Mango,Apple...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a helpful alternative, I think it would be easier to manage your dataset like this:

```
var fruits = {
    "Banana" : 1,
    "Orange" : 1, 
    "Lemon"  : 1, 
    "Apple"  : 2, 
    "Mango"  : 1
};
```

or even...

```
var fruits = [
    {type : "Banana", qty : 1},
    {type : "Orange", qty : 1}, 
    {type : "Lemon",  qty : 1}, 
    {type : "Apple",  qty : 2}, 
    {type : "Mango",  qty : 1}
];
```

Then `fruits[3].qty; // 2`

Answer (score 0):

Array.slice extracts a sub-range of an array. The '4' you have hard-coded is the end of the slice, it's not the number of items to extract. Thus, when you enter '2', you get the third and fourth elements; when you enter '3', you're extracting just the fourth item of the array, i.e. fruits[3].